# System crashed: uefi firmware updated not supported

Tags: ubuntu, bios, hardware-failure, uefi

I'm unable to understand the reason behind this error and system restart.
I have attached the log file screenshot here for understanding.

[System Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHeOc.png)

Comment: What did you try? What did you do before you encountered that error?

Comment: I work on my project related to JavaScript back-end and i don't know somehow it restarted with a screen blink